# FFMPEG Aspect Ratio HTML5 Video

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, video.js

Currently have a bunch of still images, sized: 352:240.

I use the standard ffmpeg on the files and create an mp4 or an ogv dependent on my situation.  However, when I open the video file in videoJS it's being forced into a 4:3 aspect ratio so the image is not in it's true form.

Is there an additional command I can tail onto the ffmpeg to keep the video size correctly or the ratio at a 1:1?

Comment: Is the video in 4:3 or is the video.js/video tag forcing it to 4:3?  You can tell if you open up the mp4 directly in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was forcing the size, resolved it by doing the following:

ffmpeg -r ' + str(FRAME_RATE) + ' -i ' + directory_name + '\img%d.jpg -vf "scale='+str(imgSize[0])+':'+str(imgSize[1])+',setsar=1:1" ' + directory_name

That fixed it